# How to deal with a judgmental instructor

Tags: tae-kwon-do, teaching, etiquette, social

Instructor behavior observed:

- Comparing students with each other
- Blaming students
- Insulting students
- Impulsive decisions
- Lack of discipline in teaching martial arts
- Going mostly spontaneous and with the flow
- ...

Well, an instructor with decades of martial arts experience might have some unfavorable traits.

This behavior might result in student mind noise. It takes lots of meditation to fend off the noise.

How to deal with it? If it's not possible to change the place you go to.

Comment: Sounds like you're not having a good time there. You're hoping there's some way to make it tolerable, because you don't want to leave? I think you know that's not going to happen. I would ask, if the instructor's teaching style is so bad, why are you sticking around? You think this is the best you can do where you are? Suit yourself, but life is short. Spend time with people who build you up, not tear you down. You'll be better off in the long run, even if it means you don't have anywhere to train in the short run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch instructors. Unless this instructor is like... an Olympic level coach with decades of experience and you really love the sport, just go look for other instructors. We had a ton of kids from Korea switch over to here a couple years ago because there were a couple younger instructors (my coach likes to call them 21 year old hotshot who thinks they know everything). Martial arts is about disciplining yourself and growing as a person. The comment above pretty sums it up well. I guess you could bring this up with your instructor with a bunch of other students if you want? I'd switch.

Goodluck.